# Can I Have Some Insight Into This Probabilistic Clustering Algorithm?

Tags: probability, self-study, classification, algorithms

I'm going over past exam papers and there's a question on probability clusterin algorithms that I'm not really sure how to approach. It goes as follows:

*A probabilistic clustering algorithm based on a mixture of Student’s T distributions has been trained on a labelled dataset consisting of pairs of the form (x,c), where x, is a real number and c ∈ {1,2} is a class label. The result is a distribution:*

$$
f(x)=p_1 f(x \mid c=1)+p_2 f(x \mid c=2)
$$

*where*

$$
f(x \mid c=j)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\kappa_j}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\kappa_j \pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{\kappa_j}{2}\right)}\left(1+\frac{\left(x-\mu_j\right)^2}{\kappa_j}\right)^{-\frac{1+\kappa_j}{2}}
$$

*Given that the parameters are:*

| j | $p_j$ | $k_j$ | $μ_j$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.8 | 2.5 | 3 |

***Compute the probability that an unclassified point with x = 1 belongs to class c=2***

I'm having trouble even beginning to approach this problem and would like some pointers (or preferably a full solution) if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: You are either looking for $\Pr(x = 1 \mid c = 2)$ or $\Pr(c = 2 \mid x = 1)$. Which one do you think it is?

Comment: @mhdadk I think it's the second one. So then do I first input the parameters for j = 1 and then 2 in the table; then place the values inside the Bayes' theorem equation?

Comment: Try that and see what happens. Note that the objective of this exercise is for you to learn. Even if you end up not getting anywhere, you will end up learning what didn’t work in this situation, which will inform your future decision making.